# Function that is called before every dispatch

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, axios

in my app I have want if the user is not verified to not call the dispatch actions which calls the API Endpoint.

Is there a function I can call before every redux action call I do.

I know I can add a hook add wrap every call with it, but I am searching for a more abstract way, also I have many actions.

Thank you, your help is appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at middlewares?

Comment: If your app is going to have multiple  screens you will find something like react-navigation useful. If you end up using react-navigation then you probably will have an auth flow where certain screens are inaccessible without authentication, and assuming that the api calls are being made from those screens, it would resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

As guillaume said custom middleware can be solution for this use case.

```
const yourCustomMiddleware = storeAPI => next => action => {
    if (action.type !== 'FOO') { // Check authorized
        return next({type: 'dummy'}); //if not authroized
    } else {
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, is there a clear documentation on how to write redux custom middlewares ?

Comment: Also, can we apply a middleware listener that listens for specific function calls ?

Comment: @warCommander https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware Here is tutorial about writing middleware